# Embedding LaTeX content in Flash animation

Tags: actionscript-3, latex, embedding

I would like to create a flash presentation for a web page. It would read content from files in `LaTeX` format and would display the content properly. This would require to call a `LaTeX` compiler and generate the proper output every time the content in the latex files changes. How can I do that? Any other ideas around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a good example of it at http://www.flashandmath.com/basic/latex/index.html that uses the LaTeXtoSWF library, from http://www.tlhiv.org/LaTeX2swf/

Comment: but this doesn't exactly offer a  dynamic solution - roundabout having to type it into the cgi form, then import to flash :-(

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in my open source project http://sourceforge.net/projects/latex2flash/ as well.

Here's the blog site http://validi.fi/latex2flash